# How to get an html element from document.form

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a situation where I need to get the element in JavaScript from `document.form.elementname` but the problem is that, my element name contains '.' periods in it.

So in actual its like `document.form.my.stack.element` where "`my.stack.element`" is the name of element. Changing the name is not in my hands and cannot be done so `getElementById` is the only solution left?

Please let me know if I can still get the element using its name from the form?

Comment: and why you don't just use getElementById ?

Comment: simple - use document.form[]

Comment: You're sure you didn't mean `document.forms`, with an `s` ?

Comment: @Alaeddine, exactly - `my.stack.element` is a completely valid id (or name for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `document.form['my.stack.element']`.

**HTML**

```
<form name="form">
  <input name="my.stack.element">
</form>
```

Comment: Oh yes, setting the name to the form works! Didnt do that, using ID's mostly :) Sorry! and +1.

Comment: @davidkonrad - Is your form named `form`, this only works because of global namespacing where element names are attached to the global scope, there's no such thing as `document.form` natively in javascript, hence my question in the comments quite some time ago ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can use is the square bracket notation to access the properties of an object.

So you could use

```
document.form["my.stack.element"];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can access form names by using it as an associative array. The .name is just an alternative to the associative array key example.

```
document.form.my.stack.element
```

is same as

```
document.form['my.stack.element']
```

Please note that the first snippet is an example. Of course it doesn't work because the js would treat is as an array, threatening it as `document.form['my']['stack']['element']` due of punctuations.

Comment: It is definitely not the same :-). `document.form.my.stack.element` is the same as `document.form['my']['stack']['element']`...

Comment: yes, was editing the post. Added that the first one is an example. Thanks for heads up